# Android Studio: getting an input from user

Tags: android, user-interface, input

I'm new to Android Studio. I would like to read input from user from a dynamically created elements. I've already managed to create the elements. Now I do not know at which place should I place the reading element. Can someone give me a MWE here ? I do not know also if I should use `getText(this)` or `editText(this)` or something else.

```
  public void click(View view) {
        String col1;
        String col2;

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        TextView c = new TextView(this);

        EditText etUserInfoNewValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);

        tv.setText("This is text");

        tl.addView(row);

        row.addView(tv);

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

            col1 = "(" + x + ")"+Integer.toBinaryString(x);
            col2 = "1";

            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

            TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView column2 = new TextView(this);
            EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);

            TextView column3 = new TextView(this);


            column1.setText(col1);
            column1.setText(col1);
            column2.setText(col2);

            newRow.addView(column1);
            newRow.addView(editText1);


             newRow.addView(column3);

            tl.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show how you dynamically create elements.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your hint. Please see my edit.

Comment: textView.getText() for a TextView. editText.getText() for an EditView.

Comment: @blackapps What's the difference between  TextView and EditView ? Could you provide full code for reading it including listenOnClick ?

Comment: That was a typo. I ment EditText. And that was full code already. And i have no idea why you speak about listenOnClick. I think you should better formulate what you want and what you need.

Comment: @blackapps I need to get data from EditText element once I press button4. I do not know when is used `listenOnClick`. Can you please modify my code in my Question with this `EditText` stuff ? Also when I type the name `col2` from another function `click4()` it is red as it is not available.

Comment: Sorry, i can not follow you. You are using dynamically created EditTexts. But if they were static (declared at design time) could you get their texts?

Comment: Further there is nothing to modify in your code as that code creates the views. Reading those views would require adding code. You have five rows with each an edittext.  And what you say is that you want to get data from edittext element. From which one i would ask?

Comment: @blackapps No I cannot get the contents before running the application. I want to enter the data and after pressing `button4` I want to read what was entered.

Comment: @blackapps I want to read all five edittext elements, assuming that they are all filled in. I do not know what code should I add to employ `button4` yielding obtaining the five edittexts' contents. You seem to understand the problem well enough so that you can help me, right ?

Comment: I will not help you if you can not formulate which problems you encounter to program what you want.

Comment: @blackapps I have 5 rows created after pressing first button called button2 in my xml file each containing 2 elements (a text on the l.h.s. and a free area to be filled in by the user at the r.h.s. at runtime with 5 decimal numbers). Now I've created a second button called button4 in my xml file. I wish to obtain a functionality of this `button4` which would read all the five numbers and store/get them into my code for further handling.

Comment: Ok. And... What is the problem doing so? What is it that prevents you to write that code?

Comment: @blackapps I've been using AS for 1 week only.My problem is that I do not know where should I add the code for `button4`, and also how would I detect it was pressed (I believe it is named so in my .xml file). On the one hand it should have it's own `public void click4()` function, but on the other hand it needs to access the data used in `click2()` function. Also,finally, I'm unable to write the code as required by accessing the dynamically created rows with all that `getText()` stuff around. Your directly provided code would help me a lot to learn something for the future.

Comment: @blackapps The problem is that things are just too complex for me to solve them all at once.

Comment: If you want to learn Android then do not start with dynamically created views. And there are hundreds of example projects where you could start with.

Comment: @blackapps I need this because I'm going to implement the Shapley Value from game theory. You could easily complete my code to incorporate the essential things, could you please do that? I need a row for each coalition which is a subset of {1,...,n} with `n` unknown in advance. Hence my dynamic concept. I was happy to create the code above, but now I cannot move on.

Comment: @blackapps If you cannot write the code so please at least give me a series of actions needed to do it. I'm a mathematician not a programmer.